# html2canvas.js not Working in IE9/10/11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

We want to capture screenshot of Div (HTML element) which is inside an IFrame. IFrame loads inside another Div at runtime in a html page. For capturing  screenshot we are using html2canvas.js API.

Code is working very well with Mozilla and Chrome but not working in IE9/10/11.

The basic requirement is that to capture screenshot of Div and send that image byte-array to Flex application.

Function which captures screenshot is:

```
function capturImage() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        proxy: "server.js",
        useCORS: true,
        onrenderd: function (canvas) {
            var imageData = canvas.todataURL('image/png', 1.0);
            imageDataOnly = imageData.split(",");
            falshObj.getImage(imageDataOnly[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

Error In IE:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'getComputedStyle' File: html2canvas.js, Line: 2269, Column: 5

Please let me know if anyone had similar experience or has any clue in resolving the issue.

Comment: Here's the github issues page for html2canvas. Have you searched for the same issue there? Obviously if this is a bug in their script, they are the only ones who can help you. https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues

Comment: Do the simplified demos on their site work for you?

Comment: Insert IE joke here...

Comment: Have you tried a getComputedSTyle polyfill? IE9 should support it but who knows....

Comment: What version of the `html2canvas` are you using ? What version of Windows are you using ? When you open the page which cause the problem on IE, does IE switch to compatibility mode/view ? There's an open issue regarding this problem at GitHub (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/163) and also a pending pull request for that (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/219). Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [gitHub issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/409) (that seems to be filled by you), you should not use the `proxy` and the `useCORS` properties at the same time.