# Exporting dhtmlxChart with html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, dhtmlx, html2canvas

I'm trying to export a dhtmlxChart created via an XSL to an image so people can save it. (export to MS excel failed)

The chart is build properly and works fine, so i added a button "Save as pic" that should create a canvas from the body and open it in a new page.

When i try to run it, it gives an error: 
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getComputedStyle' 
html2canvas.js, line 2269 character 5

Here is my xsl code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:decimal-format name="format" grouping-separator="." decimal-separator=","/>

<!-- Declaratie variabelen -->
<!-- Globale variabelen -->
    <xsl:variable name="VarMaand"><xsl:value-of select="//rows/row[last()]/@Maand" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="VarJaar"><xsl:value-of select="//rows/row[last()]/@Jaar" /></xsl:variable>
<!-- Einde Declaratie variabelen -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <style>
                td  {   border:1px;
                        border-style:solid;
                        border-color:#000000;
                        height:20px;
                        text-align:center;
                    }
            </style>
            <head>
                <script src="/LIB/JS/dhtmlxSuite/dhtmlxChart/codebase/dhtmlxchart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/LIB/JS/dhtmlxSuite/dhtmlxChart/codebase/dhtmlxchart.css"/>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/LIB/JS/html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <script>
                    var chart;
                    window.onload = function() {
                        chart = new dhtmlXChart({
                            view:"stackedBar",
                            container:"chart1",
                            value:"#Value1#",
                            width:10,
                        xAxis:{lines: false,template:function(obj, common, data){
                                if (obj.Maand%2) 
                                {if (obj.Maand &lt; 10) return "0"+obj.Maand+"/"+(obj.Jaar-2000);
                                            return obj.Maand+"/"+(obj.Jaar-2000);}
                                    return "";
                            }},
                            yAxis:{start:27000,step:500,end:37500},
                            color:"#0070C0"
                        });
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value2#",color:"#00B0F0"});
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value3#",color:"#00B050"});
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value4#",color:"#92D050"});
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value5#",color:"#C3D69B"});        
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value6#",color:"#D9D9D9"});
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value7#",color:"#BFBFBF"});
                        chart.addSeries({value:"#Value8#",color:"#7F7F7F"});
                        chart.addSeries({view:"spline",item:{radius:0,type:"square",color:"#000000"},line:{color:"#000000",width:2},value:"#Value9#"});
                        chart.load("../../../ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/L1/HRB/HRB_Foto_Grafiek_Data.xml",function(){},"xml")
                    }

                    function Capture()
                    {
                        html2canvas(document.body, {
                            logging:true,
                            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                            var img = canvas.toDataURL()
                                window.open(img);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                </script>
                <div id="main" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                <div id="Picture" style="width:20%;height:75%;float:left;text-align:center;">
                        <br /><img src="/LIB/IMAGE/HRB/Divers/MindTheGap.png"/><br /><br />
                        <button onclick="Capture()">Save as Pic</button>
                </div>      
                <div id="chart1" style="width:75%;height:75%;float:right;font-family:sans-serif;"></div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only log i get from html2canvas is:
LOG: html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images 
After this log entry, i get the error message stated above.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I'm trying to run in in IE9 (provided by company and can not change it)
Should I include more js in the head?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem with html2canvas.js and IE - see [html2canvas.js not Working in IE9/10/11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660102/html2canvas-js-not-working-in-ie9-10-11). I've just checked the current version [html2canvas on github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/dist/html2canvas.js) in case you're probably using an older one, but they still have at least one line calling getComputedStyle.

The problem with getComputedStyle is that this function is not supported by several IE versions, though e.g. on caniuse is stated that it'd only be not supported by IE8 - [caniuse getcomputedstyle](http://caniuse.com/#search=getcomputedstyle).

Next problem could be the IE9 version your company uses - you could easily check if getComputedStyle is working there but as the error occurs, guess not. So I'd suggest two approaches for a workaround: if you're not using the current version of html2canvas.js, check if it's working for you with the new one. And if not, as mentioned there's only one line - line 534  in the function `NodeContainer.prototype.computedStyle`- calling this function and it looks like the current version might handle the case that getComputedStyle is not supported.

If the current html2canvas.js won't work for you, you can try to add a fix for this missing function. Won't go into detail here as maybe it'll already fix your issue to update to the current version, but if you e.g. google "getcomputedstyle for ie" you'll find several resources providing js-snippets to "add" this function for IE (= a function called getComputedStyle that works for IE, is added to the window object and possibly leads to the same results like the original function) . Though some comments there state that the suggested fixes won't work, it's possible to check then if at least your script is running on IE9 or if it would have other issues.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I tried replacing the html2canvas.js file and now i don't get the error 'getcomputedstyle'. In fact i don't get anything at all. It just calls my function 'capture()' and that's it. I don't get an image in a new window but i don't get an error message either. Am I calling the html2canvas correctly?

Comment: A bit of trial and error has learned me that my page is going into quirks mode (if it isn't in this mode my dhtmlx won't work) and html2canvas doesn't seem to work in quirks mode. If i create a little page to try the html2canvas in normal mode, it works just fine. Even though, then i still can't create the canvas in a new window, append works fine, in a new window it opens a new tab and that's it... the url is a string64 but the page remains empty... even if the length is just around 2500chars.

Comment: If I get you right it's now (almost) working for you, If so, glad to hear :) . For the other issue - maybe sounds weird, but have you just tried to append it to the actual dom (maybe in a 2nd step as hidden element) and when appended, open a new window with this element? Googled around a bit for this issue, searched a bit in the github-issues of h2canvas, but issues there are diff from yours (e.g. not showing img at all caused by cross-domain policy which can be set with h2c params; not using the logging-param as it may lead to conflicts + should only be used for tests; or timing issues; etc).

Comment: I almost got it working now (when appending it to the actual dom). The only problem i still have is that my graph isn't exported correctly: only the values appear when i create the canvas (values from x-axis and y-axis, values from legend...) but the lines and the actual data of the graph isn't shown on the canvas. The script doens't give any errors. Any idea why this is? I found something about an 'tainted' canvas, but i don't really understand what this means, maybe i should be looking into this a bit more?